# How does the bwarea function of matlab work and how can I implement it in C?

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv, matlab

I want to understand the working of the `bwarea` function of MATLAB. Also I want to implement this function in C.  Any idea about how to implement will be very helpful.

Also is there a substitute for `bwarea` in opencv?

Thanks.

Comment: The manual describes the algorithm: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/images/ref/bwarea.html.

Comment: Yeah it describes..but I am having hard time in understanding this,can You explain this..??

Comment: Which part are you having trouble understanding?  It loops over each pixel in turn, and assigns it an "area" based on those rules.

Comment: You mean to say that it calculates area for each pixel..and at the end just sum all the areas?How can I implement it in C?

Comment: With some nested loops.  I would suggest writing the algorithm in Matlab first, and only then translating it to C.

Comment: I have already used bwarea in matlab,now I am trying to implememnt it in c.Should I first count all the on pixels in image?

Comment: I mean try writing your own implementation in Matlab.  Once you have that correct, then translate it into C.

Comment: ok,let me try,first I must count the on pixels in the image,right?

Answer (score 4):

The manual suggests to examine the pixels by 2-by-2 neighbours.
These neighbours can take 6 different patterns which I tried to picture here. Examining each and every 2-by-2 neighbour and calculating the total is how bwarea works.

[image: allOn]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]